# Why is Set.prototype.has() much faster than Array.prototype.includes()? Node v10

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

I have two arrays of strings, both having a length of ~150000.
I wanted to find shared elements between the two, so I used filter() on array1, and for each element checked if array2.includes[array1element].
this was taking around 1.5 mins to finish executing,
however when I changed the arrays to sets, and used set2.has(set1element), it executed in <1s
to filter.
I spread the contents of set1 into an array, but searching is being done on set2 using Set.prototype.has().

I'm new to sets, I actually just discovered them because arrays were taking so long to search through and I was looking for alternatives.
Can someone explain why there is such a significant time difference? I don't have much of a maths background so answers with less mathematical/algorithmic jargon are appreciated!

CODE:
where wireBpath and wireApath are arrays of strings: runtime ~1.5mins

`let intersections = wireBpath.filter(position => wireApath.includes(position));`

where wireBpath is an array(spread from a set to use the filter() method), and wireApath is a set: runtime<1s

````
let intersections = wireBpath.filter(position => wireApath.has(position));```
````

Comment: The performance difference is precisely the reason for having an alternative data structure. The Set implementation involves a data structure specifically designed for fast key lookups. The Array `includes()` method has to search through the entire array to look for a particular value.

Comment: Ah thanks. Any insight into how the set avoids having to look through every value?

Comment: Well it's involved; if you're not familiar with general computer science principles like algorithm efficiency it's somewhat complicated. Suffice to say that the elements of the set are stored with some sort of indexing mechanism that makes lookup fast at the expense of extra overhead when elements are added.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `the time complexity` is different for `Set` and `Array`

The methods used by Sets to search for items has a time complexity of just `O(1)`, but the methods an array uses to search for items has a linear time complexity of `O(N)`. In other words, the run-time increases at the same rate as the size of the data increases.

For more details you can see [this article](https://medium.com/@bretcameron/how-to-make-your-code-faster-using-javascript-sets-b432457a4a77)